# Azure update secret key of a app registration

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

We are trying to update secret key of an azure app registration.
We are doing this by using the Azure AD Graph API.

In the process we are using the token which is obtained from using the same application id.

However we are getting this below error

`"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."`

Is it not possible to update the key from the same App registration/Service Principal?

Interestingly::
The same request works from the https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/

Though here I belive Appregistration/Service Principal token is not used and rather a direct user login is used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have enough permission in your application in order to change the secret key.

I think you should enable the permissions I show in the image

[image]

I hope I could have helped you.

Comment: I have now added the same permission and clicked on save. I still see the same error. Do I need to grant permission as well?

Comment: It seem even I need global admin rights to grant these accesses! Not sure why global admin is needed when all I am doing is changing my own secret keys.

Comment: Even though we are able to perform same task without global admin role when we are using Azure Ad Graph Explorer.